# How do I declare a development dependency in project.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

In my `project.json`, I need to refer to a library that I'm using during development, but don't want included in the project output. This is common for things like static analyzers and other tools.

Before `project.json`, this was handled by a metadata tag in the package `.nuspec` file. But, this no longer works (as far as I know) for projects following the new JSON standard.

How do I declare a development-only dependency in the new standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `1.0.0-rc1`, the correct syntax is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "HelloShared": { 
        "version": "0.1-beta-*",
        "type": "build"
    }
},
```

This declares `HelloShared` as a build (development-only) dependency of the current project.

I found this example in [dnx/samples/HelloWorld/project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/199bc294b6c0958336a4a6d5c9eb5b9d31582fa2/samples/HelloWorld/project.json) on Github.

Comment: hey, is it possible to do it permamently for packages? Whenever I update HelloShared, type gets cleared

Comment: @Zbigniew How are you updating the package? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Through visual studio

Comment: Create a sample project and try to install Json, then add type: build, then change the json version. It will remove type: build

Comment: @Zbigniew Try editing the version string in `project.json` instead of updating with the Nuget GUI.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution because it's quite a big project. How is this possible that BASIC functionality is not implemented correctly?

Comment: Anyway I just noticed that with project.json all dependencies are not included in a nuget packages.

Comment: @Zbigniew The Visual Studio tooling is still in "preview" and has known bugs. It's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Project.json has a [publishOptions:exclude](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) section.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Fixed the link, but I wouldn't use project.json anymore if I were you... Migrate to .csproj: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj